# Non-responsive Gmail: reply screen too wide for high resolution screens

Tags: gmail

I just changed my laptop and the new one has higher resolution. This is great as I can have more info on a page.

But it is a pain in Gmail: when writing a new email, the textarea is 560px wide which is nice. On the other hand, when replying, the textarea is full screen wide, which makes it very uncomfortable to read/write.

[image: Gmail too wide]

Is there a way to restrict email view length to a certain width? 
Ain't Gmail interface responsive?

Comment: I'm sure you could add some user styles to restrict the width via an extension like [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha). The relevant CSS property is `max-width`, but I can't test because I don't have a screen like yours